# Signing Android apk using Cordova 5.0.0

Tags: cordova, apk, signed

I created a project and built successfully an  android-debug.apk. 
Now trying to get android-release-signed.apk, I created a keystore called my-release-key and stored it in both /android and my root director (just to be on the safe side).  Then using other similar answered questions: ie: [cordova 5.0 generate signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653389/cordova-5-0-generate-signed-apk)

I created a release.signing.properties file inside platforms/android and in it I put 
        `storeFile=C:\\Users\\E\\Documents\\VS2015\\Projects\\Demo\\my-release-key.keystore
          storeType=jks
          keyAlias=test
          // optional :
           keyPassword=test123
           storePassword=test123`

Then I used cmd `Cordova build android --release`

but in my outputs/apk folder always it puts out android-release-unsigned.apk

Where is it going wrong? It gets frustrating.    Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference: `release.signing.properties` should be `release-signing.properties`  Everything else looks good. Any additional messages in the console when you build?

Comment: Good catch but that was just my typo here, I have release-signing.properties in the platforms/android folder.  Now just to make sure;  I deleted this file from the folder and did again  Cordova build android --release to see if it builds and it did with out any error and again put out    android-release-unsigned.apk .   So for me it looks the release-signing.properties file did not have any effect on it (either there or not in the folder).  Is there something I should modify on the build GRADLE file that is located in platforms/andorid?  or what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm.  I only had to create that file, as build.gradle was already expecting the file.  There should be a snippet of code in build.gradle that looks like this: `if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}`

Also, when this successfully works, you should have three apks.  Unaligned, unsigned and signed.

Comment: I get android-debug.apk and android-debug.unaligned.apk  if I use the command  "cordova build android",   but I get the android-release-unsigned.apk only if I use the command "cordova build android --release". So no luck on getting android-release-signed.apk.  However, I found this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html   and it doesn't seem to be concerned about getting  the  android-release-signed.apk. because it is saying the jarsigner command signs the apk in place (without changing its name) and then just use zipalign.